# High performance computation of mean 2D-Euclidian-distance

Tags: matlab, performance, mean, euclidean-distance, integral

Let's say I have a position matrix `P` with dimensions `10x2`, where the first column contains `x` values and second column the corresponding `y` values. I want the mean of the lengths of the positions. The way I have done this so far is with the following code:

```
avg = sum( sqrt( P(:,1).^2 + P(:,2).^2))/10);
```

I've been told that the integral function `integral2` is much faster and more precise for this task. How can I use `integral2` to compute the mean value?

Comment: What's wrong with your current method (does it not provide the correct value? Is it too slow? Not general enough)? Why do you _need_ to switch to [`integral2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html) all of a sudden? Is this a homework assignment? Instead of describing the input, just add it to your question - it's not that big.

Comment: Thanks for response. The reason; soon I will work with hundreds of positions, and according to my teacher the function integral2 is much faster and more precise (which I dont know why).

Comment: There's `pdist2` if you have the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox. Notice that `integral2` is open-source, so there's no magic there. Your method is almost ideal as far as I can tell. In any case, you should always benchmark solutions before deciding what is the best approach.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so this question doesn't remain unanswered:

```
function q42372466(DO_SUM)
if ~nargin % nargin == 0
  DO_SUM = true;
end

% Generate some data:
P = rand(2E7,2);

% Correctness:
R{1} = m1(P);
R{2} = m2(P);
R{3} = m3(P);
R{4} = m4(P);
R{5} = m5(P);
R{6} = m6(P);

for ind1 = 2:numel(R)
  assert(abs(R{1}-R{ind1}) < 1E-10);
end

% Benchmark:
t(1) = timeit(@()m1(P));
t(2) = timeit(@()m2(P));
t(3) = timeit(@()m3(P));
t(4) = timeit(@()m4(P));
t(5) = timeit(@()m5(P));
t(6) = timeit(@()m6(P));

% Print timings:
disp(t);


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Original method:
function out = m1(P)
  if DO_SUM
    out = sum( sqrt( P(:,1).^2 + P(:,2).^2))/max(size(P));
  else
    out = mean( sqrt( P(:,1).^2 + P(:,2).^2));
  end
end

% pdist2 method:
function out = m2(P)
  if DO_SUM
    out = sum(pdist2([0,0],P))/max(size(P));
  else
    out = mean(pdist2([0,0],P));
  end
end

% Shortened method #1:
function out = m3(P)
  if DO_SUM  
    out = sum(sqrt(sum(P.*P,2)))/max(size(P));
  else
    out = mean(sqrt(sum(P.*P,2)));
  end    
end

% Shortened method #2:
function out = m4(P)
  if DO_SUM  
    out = sum(sqrt(sum(P.^2,2)))/max(size(P));
  else
    out = mean(sqrt(sum(P.^2,2)));
  end    
end

% hypot
function out = m5(P)
  if DO_SUM
    out = sum(hypot(P(:,1),P(:,2)))/max(size(P));
  else
    out = mean(hypot(P(:,1),P(:,2)));
  end
end

% (a+b)^2 formula , Divakar's idea
function out = m6(P)
  % Since a^2 + b^2 = (a+b)^2 - 2ab, 
  if DO_SUM
    out = sum(sqrt(sum(P,2).^2 - 2*prod(P,2)))/max(size(P));
  else
    out = mean(sqrt(sum(P,2).^2 - 2*prod(P,2)));
  end
end

end
```

Typical result on my R2016b + Win10 x64:

```
>> q42372466(0) % with mean()
    0.1165    0.1971    0.2167    0.2161    0.1719    0.2375

>> q42372466(1) % with sum()
    0.1156    0.1979    0.2233    0.2181    0.1610    0.2357
```

Which means that your method is actually the best of the above, by a considerable margin! 
(Honestly - didn't expect that!)